# Jquery $.when with multiple Ajax request problems

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to make multiple ajax request using Jquery to get Json data from a PHP file. This is my code:

```
var req = $.when($.get('file.php?load=products'),$.get('file.php?load=config'),$.get('file.php?load=settings'));

req.done(function(products,config,settings){
  console.log(products);
  console.log(config);
  console.log(settings);
});
```

The problem is that instead of getting the Json requested data alone, the data comes with additional objects like: `Object { readyState=4, responseText="[{ "value": 5, "sku": ".../uploads/coffee.png" }]", status=200, more...}]` which cause errors when I try to parse the Json data.

When I take a look at the returned parameters by my PHP script, everything looks fine, and it even works fine if I don't use the `$.when` method and instead use a simple callback with each ajax request.

I need to use the `$.when` method because I need to execute things after this three ajax calls are completed.

Hope you can help me, thanks!

EDIT:
Ok, I don't know why, but it works if I use: `products[0]` instead of `products`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when):

Example: Execute a function after two ajax requests are successful. (See the jQuery.ajax() documentation for a complete description of success and error cases for an ajax request).

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

So you are indeed receiving an array of arguments, one for each ajax call. Each argument is an array of `[data, textStatus, jqXHR]`

By reading products[0], you are accessing `data`.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a bold, radical move, but - have you considered just taking the data you actually want to use? That is: `products.responseText`, `config.responseText` and `settings.responseText`?

Comment: thanks, for your comment, but `products.responseText` returns `undefined`, it works if I use `products[0]` instead